# Interchange time and linear scaling depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a widget to let users decide what quantities to plot against what quantities (building off this [animated scatter plot](http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/bd12f73d0b79d70bfbae) on bl.ocks. This is working fine for numeric quantities, but I also have date quantities, and I want users to be able to plot these too, in the same way, and against non-date quantities.

The original linear scaling and axes are set up like so as global functions:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()  // xScale is width of graphic
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0];  // input domain
    })])
    .range([padding, canvas_width - padding * 2]); // output range

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()  // yScale is height of graphic
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1];  // input domain
    })])
    .range([canvas_height - padding, padding]);  // remember y starts on top going down so we flip

// Define X axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

// Define Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);
```

My hope was that I could modify these globals inside the `click` function and even change the nature of the scaling and that this would feed back into the axis variables as well, so I put this inside the click function:

```
if(types[xName]==3){
    console.log("resetting x scale to time type");
    xScale = d3.time.scale().range([padding, canvas_width - padding * 2]); // output range      
}
else{
    // Create scale functions
    xScale = d3.scale.linear()  // xScale is width of graphic
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0];  // input domain
    })])
    .range([padding, canvas_width - padding * 2]); // output range


}

    xScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0]; })]);
if(types[xName] == 1){
        xScale.domain([d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d[0]; }), 0]);
}

if(types[yName]==3){
    console.log("resetting y scale to time type");
    yScale = d3.time.scale().range([canvas_height - padding, padding]);  // remember y starts on top going down so we flip
}
else {
    yScale = d3.scale.linear()  // yScale is height of graphic
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1];  // input domain
    })])
    .range([canvas_height - padding, padding]);  // remember y starts on top going down so we flip
}

    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1]; })]);
if(types[yName] == 1){
        yScale.domain([d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d[1]; }), 0]);
}
```

I also use a `parseDate` as appropriate on the data when it's date data. The above (and full code is [here](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/d3/reddit/scatterplots/scatter.js) with [widget here](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/d3/reddit/scatterplots/), the problematic date type being stored in `Created`) puts all the points in some crazy location all in one straight line off the graph when I choose the date type, and worse still produces the following error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="naN" where I assume this is giving an error from the following code:

    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)  // Update with new data
        .transition()  // Transition from old to new
```

...
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[0]);  // Circle's X
            })

So I assume the `xScale` is simply not working when it's been converted to a time scale. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any corrections or troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 0):

The cx is calculating as NaN because the data you are storing *created*, as time stamp example:`"created":1447686953` and you are writing a parse date function.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
```

This is incorrect as the date is not in 20151223 format.

So the scale as you suggesting get calculated wrongly.

```
if(types[xName]== 3){
newNumber1 = parseDate(String(data[i][xName]));//this is wrong
}
var newNumber2 = data[i][yName]/divisor[types[yName]]//Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange);  // New random integer
if(types[yName]== 3){
newNumber2 = parseDate(String(data[i][yName]));//this is wrong
}
```

So you need to do this for converting into date:

```
    if(types[xName]== 3){
    newNumber1 = new Date(data[i][xName]*1000);
    }

    var newNumber2 = data[i][yName]/divisor[types[yName]]//Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange);  // New random integer
    if(types[yName]== 3){
    newNumber2 = new Date(data[i][yName]*1000);
    }
```

Hope this helps!